# Limit distinct values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, limit, distinct

I'm building something extremely similar to a "store locator" app. This queries by lat and lon and produces the nearest locations within a radius. This is working perfectly fine, but my database includes locations and sub-locations. I would like to be able to limit the distinct results the users get by location, while still querying and obtaining all information about the sub-location..

Say this is my result set before the distinct selection is applied:

```
| Location | Sub-Location |
+----------+--------------+
| Alpha    | Alpha North  |
| Alpha    | Alpha East   |
| Alpha    | Alpha West   |
| Beta     | Beta West    |
| Gamma    | Gamma North  |
| Gamma    | Gamma South  |
| Delta    | Delta West   |
| Delta    | Delta West 2 |
```

I need a way to can specify a range - let's say 2 - and produce the following result set:

```
| Location | Sub-Location |
+----------+--------------+
| Alpha    | Alpha North  |
| Alpha    | Alpha East   |
| Alpha    | Alpha West   |
| Beta     | Beta West    |
```

This would be the effective equivalent of producing the "two nearest" locations to the user. After a length of Googling and scouring Stack Overflow's suggestions and similar questions, I can't find anything that fits this description.

Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction, or perhaps provide a query example that can do this?

**EDIT:** This is the query I'm running with. It's a bit of a monster; includes the lat/lon query as well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM( 
(SELECT * FROM locationstable JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT location, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(47.4972680) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lon ) - radians(-122.2564740) ) + sin( radians( 47.4972680) ) 
* sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM locationstable
HAVING distance < 1
LIMIT 0, 5)
locationstable ON locationstable.location = location
)) locationstable 
LEFT JOIN informations 
ON substring(locationstable.locationsublocation, 4) = informations.storeinformations
```

Comment: Ignore sublocations to find the two closest locations, then join the result to your locations table to obtain all sublocations at those locations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about subquery?

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE Location IN (SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM sometable LIMIT 2);
```

Comment: Yup "IN()" of course, thank you. As for the "ORDER BY" - subquery itself is just an example, it would will be different for a real application.

Comment: Getting a version error using IN for the subquery. It seems like I might need to update my MySQL. I'm taking a look into that, but would this be possible using joins instead? If so, would an example be possible?

Comment: Nope, no way to do this with just joins (at least none I'm aware of :). What is your mysql version?

Comment: Looks like 5.0.96-community-nt. It's not _my_ server, and I'm not sure if I'll be able to get it upgraded. I don't believe `IN()` would work for this subquery in this version, correct?

Comment: `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: Ah, so the problem is in "IN", not in the subquery. Try "SELECT * FROM sometable JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM sometable LIMIT 2) loc ON sometable.Location = loc.Location;

Comment: Definitely got me farther. I'm getting `#1052 - Column 'Location' in on clause is ambiguous` now. Researching it at the present, but I figured I'd mention in case the cause might be obvious to anyone but me.

Comment: Can you post your exact query, please?

Comment: Started doing that the moment I posted my last comment. I added the whole thing I'm running with to the original post. Everything not specifically related to this discussion works fine, but I'm not sure if could be interfering in some way. I realize it may be a little wrong, as well; I've run through multiple incarnations, so I just copied what I have so far.

Comment: Yeah, your query reminds me of lisp (all the brackets :).

Problem is in this line: "locationstable ON locationstable.location = location".

By now you have two parts of the query named locationstable. Try to replace it with something like: "locationstable2 ON locationstable2.location = locationstable.location".

Comment: So close; getting `#1060 - Duplicate column name 'location'` now. Looking around to see if I can find out why. As an aside, thanks for working with me as much as you have. I'm definitely a novice, but thankfully I'm getting a much more firm understanding through this.

Comment: Found the problem - `SELECT * FROM locationstable JOIN` had the `location` already specified as a column. I specified the relevant column I needed and it worked. Marking as resolved. Once again, thanks. This has substantially helped me in my understanding of MySQL.